# Can't seem to get my reset button to work

Tags: javascript

I'm making an etch a sketch as a beginner project and I can't seem to get my reset button to work. I've tried removing the .active class but it doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Sorry if it looks ugly I'm just trying to get the javascript right before I make it look pretty.

```js
const container = document.querySelector('#container');
const div = document.querySelector('div')
const resetBtn = document.querySelector('button')

function createDiv() {
  const box = document.createElement('div');
  box.classList.add('box');
  container.appendChild(box);
}

function multiDiv () {
  for (let i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    createDiv()
  }
}

multiDiv()


container.addEventListener('mouseover', function (e) {
  // Add the "active" class to only divs with a "box" class
  if (e.target.matches('.box')) {
    e.target.classList.add('active');
  }
});

resetBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
  div.classList.remove('active')
})
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(16, 40px);
  border: 5px solid rgb(173, 173, 239);
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 90px;
  
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid rgb(205, 202, 202); 
  height: 40px; width: 40px; 
  border-radius: 5px;
  
}

.reset {
  margin-top: 80px;
  background-color: rgb(173, 173, 239);
  color: antiquewhite;
  width: 60px;
  height: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.active {
  background-color:rgb(43, 88, 73);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Etch A Sketch</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="etch.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Etch A Sketch</h1>

  <div id="container"></div>

  <button class="reset">Shake</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your reset button doesn't reset anything. I think you need to delete the divs inside the etchasketch and then recreate them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove "active" from all the divs with class="box active".

```
resetBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
  const list = [...document.querySelectorAll(".box .active")]; // get all active box divs
  list.forEach(box => box.classList.remove("active"));
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch all the elements with the `active` class, then loop over them removing the `active` class. `document.querySelector()` only runs once, so you need to run it whenever the button is clicked, instead of once at the beginning of your code.

```js
const container = document.querySelector('#container');
const resetBtn = document.querySelector('button')

function createDiv() {
  const box = document.createElement('div');
  box.classList.add('box');
  container.appendChild(box);
}

function multiDiv () {
  for (let i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    createDiv()
  }
}

multiDiv()


container.addEventListener('mouseover', function (e) {
  // Add the "active" class to only divs with a "box" class
  if (e.target.matches('.box')) {
    e.target.classList.add('active');
  }
});

resetBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
  const boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
  for (let i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
    boxes[i].classList.remove('active');
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(16, 40px);
  border: 5px solid rgb(173, 173, 239);
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 90px;
  
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid rgb(205, 202, 202); 
  height: 40px; width: 40px; 
  border-radius: 5px;
  
}

.reset {
  margin-top: 80px;
  background-color: rgb(173, 173, 239);
  color: antiquewhite;
  width: 60px;
  height: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.active {
  background-color:rgb(43, 88, 73);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Etch A Sketch</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="etch.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Etch A Sketch</h1>

  <div id="container"></div>

  <button class="reset">Shake</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reset button runs `.classList.remove('active')` on `div` which is actually `#container` since the variable `div` is defined once at the beginning of the script (i.e. when no  elements other than the container actually exist on the page).

You need to assign `div` after all the div elements are written in `multiDiv()`. `div` should actually store an array of all the divs on the page.

```js
...


multiDiv()
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('div')

...

resetBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
  divs.forEach(div => div.classList.remove('active'))
})
```